# Doctrine Join - has no association named

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a problem with join in Symfony Doctrine.
I have a master Entity:

```
class PosterCartelli{
   ...

   /**
    * @var int|null
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id_poster_categoria", type="integer", nullable=false)
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\PosterCategorie", inversedBy="idPosterCategoria")
    * @JoinColumn(name="id_poster_categoria", referencedColumnName="id_poster_categoria")
    */
     private $idPosterCategoria;
    ...
 }
```

And join with this Entity:

```
class PosterCategorie{

  /**
   * @ORM\Id()
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
   * @ORM\Column(name="id_poster_categoria", type="integer")
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\PosterCartelli", mappedBy="idPosterCategoria")
   */
    private $idPosterCategoria;
    ...
  }
```

My Select in PosterCartelliRepository is:

```
 return $this->createQueryBuilder('pc')
        ->andWhere('pc.stato = \'Y\'')
        ->join('pc.idPosterCategoria', 'ipc')
        ->orderBy('pc.numeroCartello', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

But I have always the same error: 
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 76 near 'ipc WHERE pc.stato': Error: Class App\Entity\PosterCartelli has no association named idPosterCategoria

I tried in different way but I don't have success.
I think that everything is correct, because PosterCartelli.idPosterCagoria is declare ManyToOne with "IdPosterCategory" and viceversa.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Remove the @ORM\Column lines as they conflict with the @ORM\OneToMany relations. Name your property $posterCategoria, not $idPosterCategoria.

Comment: … also: remove the the `JoinColumn` annotation and the `name` attribute on the `Column` annotation, they are redundant.

Comment: Thank  you @Richard and @lxg! but if I delete @ORM\Column there is an error with primary key "Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key." in PosterCategorie.

Comment: You need to add an id column, see https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony3-doctrine/entity-class

Comment: But i didn't understand  there is a primary key in PosterCategorie because is idPosterCategoria and I see in the table. Declared with * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")

Comment: Your primary key can't be a ManyToOne relation at the same time. You have an identifier as a primary key, and a ManyToOne relation, as documented here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html

Comment: ok perfect, it works! thank you so much !!